# Only websafe colours for styling a <hr>?

Tags: css

I have a `<hr>` and I need it to have the colour (hex value) #ac8900. If I style it the old fashioned way

```
<hr color="#ac8900">
```

it works fine. But I'm expected to style everything with CSS, so I tried this in my style sheet:

```
hr{
color: #ac8900;
background-color: #ac8900;
border-color: #ac8900;
height:2px;
border:none;
}
```

But it doesn't work. Other, more 'basic' colours work such as #000, #fff etc but not the one I need. Can you only colour a `<hr>` with css using web safe colours?

Comment: `#ac89` is not a valid color code. Try using a real RGB hex code (six hexadecimal digits).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your property values are invalid. you need RGB codes for the values to be valid. Try the below style.

No need of `border-color` if  `border:none`, Similarly `color` doesn't make sense here too.

```
hr{
background-color: #ac8900;
height:2px;
}
```

Comment: Like which browsers? color is applied on the text in an element. Hr cannot have any text. similarly border color is of no use when there is no border.. Please correct me if i am missing something...

Answer (score 0):

See [MDN for acceptable values for the CSS `color` data type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/color_value). There are a lot of valid ways to specify colors, including three or six digit hexadecimal numbers, `rgb()`, `hsl()`, and keywords like `red` or `cornflowerblue`.